# Rails - change default time in Time datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

In my view, I will be ordering a list of items by their `start_time`. There are instances, however, where there might be a `start_time` of 1:00 AM (*the following day*) that should show up as after a `start_time` of 11:00 PM (*previous day*). Since the Time datatype stores a default date of 2001-01-01, it considers an entry of 1:00 AM to be on 2001-01-01, not 2001-01-02.

**Thus, my question is, is there a way to change the default date in the Time datatype?**

I suppose an obvious solution would be to instead store the start and end times in a DateTime datatype and enter a corresponding date. For this application, however, it is customary to refer to a start time of 1:00 AM as "belonging to" the previous day and would thus be confusing to enter the following day's date. (*E.g. When attending your favorite band's concert on a Friday night, their set might start at 12:30 am Saturday morning, but you would still consider the concert to be on a Friday night*). Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've tagged this with "postgresql", which suggests to me that you want a way to achieve this sorting in the database, but you also talk about the Ruby `Time` class, which wouldn't be involved in that. Do you want to sort in a DB query or in Ruby code?

Comment: I'm still relatively new to RoR. I was not sure whether this was something that would be handled w/ Ruby code or a DB query.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a possible solution to your problem: you could create a custom sort that sorts times < 1 AM last.

```
sorted_concerts = Concert.order('CASE WHEN start_time <= "2001-01-01 01:00:00" THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, start_time')
```

This way you can leave the db columns as is but get your expected order for concerts. Excepting for this 1 AM inversion, the times will sort normally in ascending order.

Comment: Steve - thanks for the suggestion. It is certainly a good work around in the mean time. I'm still interested in finding a more permanent solution as there are edge cases where concerts end around 7/8 am while some day events could theoretically start that early.

Comment: Did something similar to your suggestion below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After much more research, it doesn't seem like the default date of "2001-01-01" that Ruby applies to a time stored in a Time datatype can be adjusted. I guess this answers my question - but -  to solve the problem, I changed the db columns to datetime datatype and logged a default date, that would adjust if the time entry was after midnight. Controller action below:

```
def create
      start_time = DateTime.parse("#{run_of_show_item_params[:date]} #{run_of_show_item_params[:start_time]}")
      end_time = DateTime.parse("#{run_of_show_item_params[:date]} #{run_of_show_item_params[:end_time]}")

      @run_of_show_item = RunOfShowItem.new(run_of_show_item_params)
      @run_of_show_item.start_time = start_time 
      @run_of_show_item.end_time = end_time
      @run_of_show_item.start_time+=1.days if run_of_show_item_params[:start_time] < "07:00"
      @run_of_show_item.end_time+=1.days if run_of_show_item_params[:start_time] < "07:00"
    if @run_of_show_item.save
      flash[:success] = "Performance added!"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```